# What is the probability that exactly one of two balls selected from urn B is white after two balls are transferred from urn A to urn B?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

QUESTION: "Urn A contains 6 white and 4 black balls. Urn B contains 2 white and 2 black balls. From urn A two balls are selected at random and placed in urn B. From urn B two balls are then selected at random. What is the probability that exactly one of these two balls is white?"

What I did:
Well I think there are several cases to consider when out of the 10 balls in Urn A, 2 are to be moved.

1. 2 white balls from Urn A are moved to B, so when eventually choosing out of B, there are 4 white balls and 2 black balls to choose out of.
2. 1 white ball and 1 black ball from Urn A are moved to B, so when eventually choosing out of B, there are 3 white balls and 3 black balls to choose out of.
3. 2 black balls from Urn A are moved to B, so when eventually choosing out of B, there are 2 white balls and 4 black balls to choose out of.

So total amount of cases I'm not sure, but I think is 10C2*6C2, meaning that out of the 10 in A, we choose 2 to move to B, then out of the 6 balls in B, we choose 2.

Considering each case added together, which I am wrong I think, I got 2C1*4C1+3C1*3C1+4C1*2C1

The Answer: 128/225

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach was correct, but it seems you did not calculate probability!

We have the following cases:-

**Case I: 2 White balls are taken from Urn A and transferred to Urn B**

In that case, the number of ways of choosing 2 white balls from Urn A are $6 \choose 2$ ways. And the total number of ways of choosing 2 balls from Urn A are $10 \choose 2$ ways.

Therefore, the probability of choosing two white balls from Urn A is $\dfrac{6 \choose 2}{10 \choose 2} = \dfrac{1}{3}$

Now, in Urn B we have 4 white balls and 2 black balls. If we need to choose two balls such that exactly one of the balls is white, the other must be black. Therefore, the only possible combination is: 1 white ball *and* 1 black ball.

This can be done in ${4 \choose 1}.{2 \choose 1}$ ways. And the total number of ways for choosing 2 balls from Urn B is $6 \choose 2$ ways.

Therefore, the probability of choosing exactly one white ball (out of two selected) from Urn B is $\dfrac{{4 \choose 1}.{2 \choose 1}}{6 \choose 2} = \dfrac{8}{15}$

Hence, the probability that both these events occur is the multiplication of these two probabilities. Therefore the probability that *two white balls were taken out from Urn A and then exactly one white ball is taken out from Urn B* is $\dfrac{1}{3} \times \dfrac{8}{15} = \dfrac{8}{45}$.

**Case II: 1 White ball and 1 Black ball are taken from Urn A and transferred to Urn B**

In this case, the number of ways of choosing one white ball and one black ball from Urn A is ${6 \choose 1}.{4 \choose 1}$.

The probability that this happens is $\dfrac{{6 \choose 1}.{4 \choose 1}}{10 \choose 2} = \dfrac{8}{15}$

Now, in Urn B we have 3 White balls and 3 Black Balls. The probability that after removing two balls, exactly one of them is white is $\dfrac{{3 \choose 1}.{3 \choose 1}}{6 \choose 2} = \dfrac{3}{5}$

Therefore, the probability that *one white ball and one black ball are removed from Urn A and transferred to Urn B and then exactly one (out of the two removed from Urn B) is white* is $\dfrac{8}{15} \times \dfrac{3}{5} = \dfrac{8}{25}$

**Case III: 2 Black Balls are taken from Urn A and transferred to Urn B**

The probability of removing two black balls from Urn A is $\dfrac{4 \choose 2}{10 \choose 2} = \dfrac{2}{15}$

Now, the Urn B has 2 white balls and 4 black balls. Therefore, the probability that after removing two balls from Urn B, exactly one of them is white is $\dfrac{{2 \choose 1}.{4 \choose 1}}{6 \choose 1} = \dfrac{8}{15}$

Therefore the probability that *two black balls are removed from Urn A and transferred to Urn B after which exactly one ball (out of the two removed from Urn B) is white* is $\dfrac{2}{15} \times \dfrac{8}{15} = \dfrac{16}{225}$

Since there are no more cases, we may now move towards computing the total probability. Since only one of these cases may occur at once, we have Occurrence of Case I *OR* Occurrence of Case II *OR* Occurrence of Case III.

Hence, the total probability would be $\dfrac{8}{45} + \dfrac{8}{25} + \dfrac{16}{225} = \dfrac{128}{225}$.