# Balls and Bins moving from Box A to box B

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, problem-solving

There are $100$ yellow balls and $300$ blue balls in urn I, and there are $300$ yellow balls and $100$ blue balls in urn II. You take *half* of the balls from I and transfer them to II. Then you chose one ball from II, what is the probability that this ball is yellow? Let $\mbox{Urn}_i$ (Yellow, blue) denote the number of Y and P balls in urn $i$.

---

So the first thing I did was use smaller numbers to get a better intuition.

Time $0$:
$I(1,3)
\quad II(3,1)$

Transfer Case $1$ : $(1,1)$ from $I \to II \quad$ then
$I(0,2)
\quad II(4,2)$

Transfer Case $2$ : $(0,2)$ from $I \to II \quad$ then
$I(1,1)
\quad II(3,3)$

If $Y$ denotes the event that yellow is chosen from $II$ after the transfer, then

$Pr(Y)=Pr(Y|(1,1) \mathrm{\ transfer})+Pr(Y|(0,2) \mathrm{\ transfer})$

$Pr(Y|(1,1) \mbox{ transfer})=\frac 2{(4+2)}= \frac 13$ from the final numbers in $II$ after the transfer Case 1
$Pr(Y|(0,2) \mathrm{\ transfer})=\frac 3{3+3}= \frac 12$

So $Pr(Y)=\frac 56$ using the smaller scaled problem.
Now when I scale this to a larger multiples...I don't understand the pattern to get a better intuition.

---

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488876/what-is-the-probability-that-exactly-one-of-two-balls-selected-from-urn-b-is-whi?rq=1) problem and I thought it was very similar, but I'm struggling with how to transfer the thought process from that Problem to a problem like this. However when I try and follow the process I am getting stuck.

---

**Case 1:** Event $Y$ s.t. $Pr(\mathrm{only \ Yellow\  transfered})= 0$
This is because you have $\frac{^{100}C_{200}}{^{400}C_{200}} = (0/\#)=0$. It also logically makes sense, if we have to move $200$ balls from I, and there are only $100$ Yellow balls in I, then there no way for only yellow balls to be transfered.

**Case 2** Event $P$ s.t. $Pr(\mathrm{different \ are\  transfered})$
This is where I am having some trouble. There can be $\{(1 \mathrm{\ yellow \ ball, 199\  blue}), (2 Y, 198 B), ..., (99Y, 101B)\}$ and I am stuck on how to figure out the number of ways that different balls can be transfered. If I know this then the $Pr(P)=\frac{\#\{\mathrm{different\  ball\  combinations}\}}{^{400}C_{200}}$.

After this i should do probability of picking yellow $={\mathrm{number\  of \ yellow}}{600}$. I should divide by $600$ because that is the total number of balls in $II$ after the transfer.

**Case 3** Event $B$ s.t. $Pr(\mathrm{only blue are transferred})$
this is $\frac{^{300}C_{200}}{^{400}C_{200}} = \frac{300!/(100!200!)}{400!/(200!200!)} =$ some number, but I don't understand how to simplify this. if the numbers were larger, i think i would have an overflow problem on my calculator.

However if $Pr($only  blue transfer$)=X$, then the probability of picking yellow after the transfer is $(300/600)=1/2$

Then the last step should be to add up the probabilities of each case.

Comment: Hi Lizzy, welcome to the site. I highly appreciate your detailing of your attempt, it is frankly far better than I'd expect of a new user. The downvote you have received is due to the fact that your presentation looks cluttered, primarily due to the lack of MathJax. You can use the MathJax tutorial page to help yourself use this site better.  Remember that many people will read this post of yours, so if you can read up that page and try to tidy your post it will be nice. Alternately, I can do it, but I need you to approve, and I want you to see how I do it as well by seeing my edits.

Comment: You can also attend to the answer below by commenting below it if you have any doubts. You may upvote/downvote if you agree/disagree respectively with the answer, and can accept the answer if you think it completely addresses your question.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thank you for the clarifcations, i was confused about the downvote. I can approve the edits that you make, it would be very helpful to see the MathJax and how that works. I will also check the tutorial out too

Comment: Thank you for the response Lizzy. I will make the required edits to the question. You can speak to the user who posted the answer below by commenting below his/her answer and clarifying doubts.

Comment: You can take a look at the edit I have made. Please note the MathJax that I have used for the cleaning up, along with the spaces and breaks  I used. Remember, neatness in question is a sign of dedication to your question, and a sign of respect to those attempting to read your question and help you. I am sure your next question will be far better in terms of MathJax, because honestly it is well-regarded in terms of context explanation on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\frac 23$ chance to draw a ball that was originally in urn II.  If you do, you have $\frac 34$ chance to get a yellow ball.  You have $\frac 13$ chance to get a ball that was originally in urn I.  If you do, you have $\frac 14$ chance to get a yellow ball.  The overall chance of a yellow ball is then
$$\frac 23 \cdot \frac 34 + \frac 13 \cdot \frac 14=\frac 7{12}$$

Comment: Okay, i think i get it. Generally speaking a problem like this is the $\sum Pr($balls original location)*$Pr$(Ball color). The thirds come from the total number of balls after the transfer being 600, and the break down of the balls from each urn is 200, 400.  But can you explain where the .25 and the .75 come from?

Comment: Is the .25, and the .75 coming from the fact there are a total of $400 Yellow$, but $300$ are originally from $II$ and 100 are originally from $I$?

Comment: Yes, that is where the $\frac 14$ and $\frac 34$ come from.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. However is there a way to explain how i could get to your approach from what i was originally thinking. I am asking because I generally struggle with combinatorics and its my approach that is inefficient. My general approach to any combinatorics problem, i try and create a fraction of want/total. And based on the information in the problem i consider cases.

Comment: And this is why i often struggle with these problems, I am spending time considering cases, and with numbers as large as this, it is impossible to consider a problem like this without the logic that you use. After seeing your answer, it is clear that the number of balls don't matter, but its the proportion of balls that I should focus on

Comment: I think maybe creating a $2x2$ chart, it will help me organize the information, but i don't think that will help me find the intuition to come up with the result that you explained.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are thinking too hard about the distribution of colors that are moved.  I never talked about  that.  The basic idea is just that an Urn I ball has half the chance to be picked that an Urn II ball has.

Comment: I completely agree. I guess I was looking for advice on how to adjust my thinking/approach to there problem. I think that there might be a gap in my understanding behind bominatorics

Comment: These problems often have symmetries because the computations become to difficult otherwise.  You buy yourself a lot of extra trouble if you don't find them.  A classic is drawing three cards from a deck, what is the chance the third card is an ace?  Many people worry about whether there is an ace in the first two or not even though they immediately know the chance the first card is an ace is $\frac 1{13}$.  So draw the three cards and look at them in reverse order.  Clearly now the chance the third card is an ace is again $\frac 1{13}$

Comment: wow that is a really good example. I wouldn't have thought of drawing three cards, and then looking them in reverse order.